# StatsD sends Average or Graphite stores Average instead of Sum

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am using StatsD to record Requests send to my Server, and Graphite to collect the statistics. But when I try to display the statistics, instead of a sum aggregated over a minute, I get averages.
My retention rate for the requests is 1m:7d,5m:35d,1d:1y. My xFilesFactor is 0 and my aggregationMethod is sum. The FlushInterval of StatsD is set to 1m. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you got Graphite configured correctly for aggregating the StatsD metrics? See https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Did you happen to correct the aggregation config after finding this behavior?  Graphite won't re-aggregate the existing retention intervals, it will just start summing new arrivals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statsd normalizes the point it sends to graphite over that time period on a per second basis.

The aggregationMethod is a config for Graphite retention schemas which specifies how points are aggregation as you go from (in your case) a 1m representation to a 5 minute per point representation (and so on).

If you want the number of requests over that minute period, in graphite you can multiply the series by a constant 60 and get the result.